# Using Taxize Package to Get a Dataframe of Family names from Species list

Tags: r, dataframe, taxonomy, ncbi

I am using Taxize package to get the Family names from a list of species. Please see an example below:

```
example <- c("Procyon lotor", "Bos taurus", "Homo sapiens")
example <- data.frame(example)

        example
1 Procyon lotor
2    Bos taurus
3  Homo sapiens
```

I would like to the add a column for the family name that each species belongs to:

```
        example family
1 Procyon lotor Procyonidae
2    Bos taurus Bovidae
3  Homo sapiens Hominidae
```

As of now, I have been using the tax_name function in Taxize package. The issue is that I can only do this one at a time. If I try this for the first column, I am left with a list of data frames.

```
x <- tax_name("Homo sapiens", get = 'family', db = 'ncbi')

x
    db        query    family
1 ncbi Homo sapiens Hominidae
```

I would like to run tax_name on the entire species column to yield then a family column.

Any suggestions would be appreciate! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try running it on the vector instead of the data.frame.

```r
library(taxize)

example <- c("Procyon lotor", "Bos taurus", "Homo sapiens")
exampled_df <- tax_name(example, get = 'family', db = 'ncbi')

# > example_df
# db         query      family
# 1 ncbi Procyon lotor Procyonidae
# 2 ncbi    Bos taurus     Bovidae
# 3 ncbi  Homo sapiens   Hominidae
```

Using the data.frame example, this would amount to something like,

```r
example$family <- tax_name(example$example, get = 'family', db = 'ncbi')$family
```

Comment: Ah thank you. For some reason, I tried this now, and it actually works as you would imagine. I must have been typing it wrong. Thank you!